# java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set with SentenceModel

Tags: java, opennlp

I'm using OpenNLP for syntactic analysis. I wrote these lines to load the 
 Sentence detector model:

```
    InputStream is = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("models/en-sent.bin") ;            
    SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(is);
```

the above line throws the exception: `java.util.zip.ZipException`: invalid code 
 lengths set.

The `"models/en-sent.bin"` is located under `"src/main/resources/models/en-
 token.bin"`.

When I try to print the file path using:

```
   System.out.println(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("models/en-sent.bin"));
```

The path shows as : `"file:/C:/Users/aaa/workspace/qa/target/classes/models/en-sent.bin"`.
if I load the model using:

```
    InputStream is =  new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/models/en-sent.bin") ;
    SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(is);
```

It works fine, but this method will not work when I build the file into a runnable jar. Any help why this Exception is thrown?

The full stack exception is here:

```
java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set
at java.util.zip.InflaterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.zip.ZipInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties$LineReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load0(Unknown Source)
at java.util.Properties.load(Unknown Source)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.PropertiesSerializer.create(PropertiesSerializer.java:31)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.PropertiesSerializer.create(PropertiesSerializer.java:27)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.loadModel(BaseModel.java:224)
at opennlp.tools.util.model.BaseModel.<init>(BaseModel.java:173)
at opennlp.tools.sentdetect.SentenceModel.<init>(SentenceModel.java:91)
at com.elsevier.sherpath.syntactic_analysis.QuestionNLPAnalysis.<init>(QuestionNLPAnalysis.java:88)
at com.elsevier.sherpath.main.QuestionProcessing.syntacticAnalysis(QuestionProcessing.java:255)
at com.elsevier.sherpath.main.BatchProcess.main(BatchProcess.java:23)
```

Thanks

Comment: Specifying the language tag is important : `Java`. I have just added it. Otherwise the question could not be read by `Java` users.

Answer (score 7):

You can set `resource filtering` false and include that bin file, so that it will not be affected in `mvn install`.

```
<resource>
    <directory>your resources directory</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
        <includes>
            <include>your-bin.bin</include>
        </includes>
</resource>
```

The cause of the exception is maven is trying to recreate your bin file using `pom.xml` properties and, as a result of that, the `bin` file in the target directory will not be same as in your resource folder. Therefore set `resource filtering` false for the `bin` file.

Comment: I faced this issue and struggled 1 days. Tried many plugin, solution suggested on stackoverflow in POM.xml. But it was waste. 
Finally I removed all the contents from .m2 directory and tried to build jar from command "mvn clean package" . It perfectly working for me.

Comment: I also just recompiled the project and the error was gone

Answer (score 1):

> It works fine, but this method will not work when I build the file
>   into a runnable jar. Any help why this Exception is thrown?

```
   InputStream is =  new FileInputStream("src/main/resources/models/en-sent.bin") ;
```

uses a system-dependent file name.
When you are not in a JAR, it uses as base path the folder of you project.
When you are in a JAR, it uses as base path the JAR itself.
So it cannot work.

You have two ways to solve your problem :

- either you use a classpath resource loading by specifying the resource that is in the classpath. For example `InputStream is = YourClass.class.getResourceAsStream("/models/en-sent.bin");`
  In your tries, I think that you have forgotten the `"/"` at the beginning of the path.
  Without the `"/"` you use a path relative to the package where the method is invoked.
- or you move the resource outside the JAR and you access it with an absolute path. For example : `InputStream is =  new FileInputStream("file:///D:/models/en-sent.bin");`.

Comment: Thanks for the response.
I used InputStream is = loader.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/models/en-sent.bin");
but SentenceModel sModel = new SentenceModel(is);

Comment: You are welcome :) Instead of `loader`, try with a class of your application.

Comment: the path using this line:
 System.out.println(loader.getClass().getResource("/models/en-sent.bin").getPath());
the result is :
/C:/Users/alishaim/workspace/question-assessment/target/classes/models/en-sent.bin
the path using this line:
 System.out.println(loader.getClass().getResource("/models/en-sent.bin").toURI().toString();
the result is :
file:/C:/Users/alishaim/workspace/question-assessment/target/classes/models/en-sent.bin
Does the format of the path is the problem.
I can' use absolute paths, that won't work when running this from the Jar

Comment: I tried with ClassName.Class().getResourceAsStream but still gettin the same problem.

Comment: What is your class package? The first "/" is important. Without it the path is relative.
Use getResourceAsStream. The getResource will not work outside the IDE.

Comment: So I added the "/" 
When I use 
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/models/en-sent.bin") ;
This line : 
sModel = new SentenceModel(is); 
throws a java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid code lengths set, when I run it from eclipse
When I use: InputStream is = new FileInputStream ("absolute path/en-token.bin"); It works fine through the IDE but of course won't work from the jar because of the path.

Answer (score 0):

We can also use this **Plugin**:

```
 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <nonFilteredFileExtensions>
                    <nonFilteredFileExtension>bin</nonFilteredFileExtension>
                </nonFilteredFileExtensions>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```